# What is ７つ referring to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

The following is text from the opening of the game Fire Emblem Monshou no Nazo:

> おお！　我らが母なる大地
>
> **７つを１０００も重ねた間**
>
> 絶望という時代あり
>
> 我らが　天に救いを求める事
>
> ７年と７月と７日の間

If I understand correctly, the highlighted phrase says that there was a period where 7 "somethings" were repeated 1000 times. Does this refer to years? It is not necessarily clear from the context since this is what the game opens with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing indicates it's specifically 7000 "years", so this should be taken as a myth-esque, archaic-sounding way of saying "very long time too long to measure precisely". In other words, it appears to me that it's a fancy way of saying "countless ages", not "7000 years".

This odd-looking expression should be loosely related to the fact that old Japanese (yamato kotoba) was poor at counting large numbers systematically and the fact that 8 was treated as a [pronoun for large numbers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51673/5010) (cf. [八千代](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%83%E4%BB%A3)). *Fire Emblem* is not set in Japan, but when Japanese people see an expression like this, they feel it looks like an old myth or a legend.

Answer (score 1):

> ７つを１０００も重ねた間

Probably it corresponds to [千重{ちえ}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8D-565043) which implies a huge accumulations.

According to デジタル大辞泉,

> ち‐え〔‐へ〕【千重】
> たくさん重なること。

> 「ま幸(さき)くて妹が斎(いは)はば沖つ波―に立つとも障(さは)りあらめやも」〈万・三五八三〉

I believe [八重{やえ}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8D-565043) has also a similar nuance in Japanese culture and more common.

> や‐え〔‐へ〕【八重】

> １ 八つ重なっていること。転じて、数多く重なっていること。また、そのもの。「七重の膝(ひざ)を八重に折る」

Also, [7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolism_of_the_number_7) is regarded as a symbolic number which has a great importance in many cultures.

All in all, the phrase might be a metaphor of "very long period" which is similar to the concept of [刧{こう}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8A%AB-61344).
Probably this kind of a metaphor for the time is seen in many folklore or myth in many cultures of human beings.

Comment: This is an interesting response but unless I'm missing something I don't think it directly answers my question. If I understood you correctly you interpreted the sentence to mean 千重 (many piles) of "something". I wanted to know what that "something" is. Like I said in my post, my initial guess was "years", which would mean the phrase is a fancy way of saying "7000 years" I guess. If that's the case though I don't really know for sure why it makes sense to use ７つ and not ７年.

Comment: @ssuga I felt the "something" is what you need to find in the RPG's plot . That s to say, the symbols/places/etc. what you are going through in the plots should be related to the number 7.

Comment: @kimiTanaka 本編テキストを文字起こしている[サイト](https://www.pegasusknight.com/mb/fe3/st_index.html)を見つけたのでざっと確認しましたが、本編ストーリー内で7という数字に大した意味があるわけではなさそうです。

Comment: @naruto [ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A0%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC%E3%83%A0_%E7%B4%8B%E7%AB%A0%E3%81%AE%E8%AC%8E)によると、「アカネイア大陸には**7つの王国**があり、小さな争いこそあるものの平和な状態が続いていた。たが、暗黒司祭ガーネフによって、平和の時が破られた。100年前に英雄アンリによって倒された暗黒竜メディウスがガーネフによって復活させられた。そして、再び世界を支配せんと恐怖の進撃を開始した。アンリの血を引くアリティア王コーネリアスは、神剣ファルシオンを手にメディウスに立ち向かった。しかし同盟国の裏切りによって逆襲を受けてしまう。アリティアは滅亡し、まだ幼い王子は辺境の島国タリスに逃れた。マルス王子が16歳になったとき、タリスにもメディウスの魔の手が伸びてきた。マルスはついにメディウス討伐軍を決起した。それは、長い暗黒戦争の始まりであった。」と言うプロットなので、比喩表現「長い時間」と具体的表現「7王国」のどちらも示しているのかと思いました。プレイした事があるので、あまり違和感はない解釈です。大分前ですが。

Comment: 「7」王国というのは偶然でしょう…[これ](https://w.atwiki.jp/aniwotawiki/pages/38186.html)を見る限り王国の数が7になったのはストーリー開始のわずか25年前ですし、ある時点での王国の数が神話に出てくる7と何か必然的に関係するという話ではなさそうですし。

Comment: @naruto 懐かしいので、また思い出してみます。ご指摘ありがとうございます。