# What special meanings does the number 8,000,000 have in the Japanese language and where do they come from?

Tags: japanese-to-english, classical-japanese

What special meanings does the number 8,000,000 have in the Japanese language and where do they come from?

Possible suggestions from me:

- Eternity
- Infinity

In the course of time, I have come across various indications that the number 8,000,000 could have a special meaning in the Japanese language.

One hint is for example the Japanese national anthem.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230326120623/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimigayo#/media/File:Kimigayo.score.svg

Comment: FYI: https://okwave.jp/qa/q9912959.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "many gods" (八十神) exactly eighty?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/51673/why-is-many-gods-%e5%85%ab%e5%8d%81%e7%a5%9e-exactly-eighty) If I understand correctly, there is nothing magical or mysterious about the number 8 per se. It's just a pronoun for large numbers.

Comment: I dont talk about "8", I talk about 8.000.000. So, your source cant be a answer.

Comment: @Eddy763, both the links provided by @[aguijonazo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/43676/) and @[naruto](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5010/) mention 八百万 (_yao yorozu_, "eight million"). And as naruto mentions, the key is the way the number 8 is used in older expressions to mean "a lot, a large number".

Comment: Did you really read the link I posted? It does mention 8,000,000. In situations where English speakers would say "hundreds of", "millions of", "dozens of" and so on, old Japanese people somehow said "800 of", "8000 of", "8000000 of" and so on. So 8 is the special number here, and 8000000 is one of the variants. (And the lyrics of Kimigayo has 8,000 but not 8,000,000.)

Comment: @naruto, 8.000 x 1.000 = 8.000.000 THX

Comment: @aguijonazo , your source is realy great, THX. If you write a few words with the help of your source, it should not be a problem to win the bounty for you or get extra points, if a other one win the Bounty. However, I can only thank you with points if you write a reply.

Comment: I think your own answer (or the comments here) already covers all. 8000000 means just countlessly many. According to [this](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%85%AB%E7%99%BE%E4%B8%87-647572), it appears already in [Kojiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kojiki) compiled in 712.

Answer (score 0):

Underpinned by the source below, the term 8,000,000 in Japanese has, at least among other things, the following meaning, which of course everyone may interpret quite personally and perhaps quite differently.

In Japan, the number 8,000,000 is used as an unlimited number, in connection with the naming of the number of Kami.

The term gods in Japan can be understood in the sense that the Japanese are inclined to show respect for everything and everyone, as they consider them to be sacred, animate and holy. This can be expressed, for example, by the fact that they weigh the presumed interests of their environment against their own and take these into account in their decisions.

To some observers of Japanese culture, respect for anything and everything (gods), i.e., for example, a tree, a rock, a dragonfly, a deer, a chicken, a piece of moss, a human being, or one of one's ancestors may seem to be a kind of natural religion.

For lack of a better term understandable to non-Japanese, "kami" is usually translated as "gods" to at least give an indication of what it is broadly about). In the sense that Japan is a happy country full of gods. Or it could also be interpreted to mean that Japan is a happy country because it is full of people who respect and appreciate each other.

Underpinning source: https://web.archive.org/web/20230404152618/https://okwave.jp/qa/q9912959.html

Comment: Saving the "Underpinning source" as "archive.org"  can possible optimise the answer 0.1%.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make much sense out of this sentence: _"Whereby the term gods in Japan can be understood quite in the sense that the Japanese from their culture before everything and everyone, in the positive sense respect have and the appropriate personality respect, honor and it him is sacred."_ There are some grammatical problems here.  I would edit to fix, but I don't understand your intent well enough. Could you try re-wording that?

Comment: I have changed the passage. THX.